# Why cannot a linear function of a dual space have a "constant term"?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am in first grade of my maths career and I have just started with dual spaces.

I have seen that an isomorphism between the space of vector rows of length $n$ and the dual space of $V=K^n$ can be made. However, I do not totally understand this, because if according to the definition $V^*= \{f:V \rightarrow \mathbb{K}\}$, a perfectly valid in $\mathbb{R}^3$ would be $\phi(x,y,z)= x+y+z+3$.

From what I have seen in books, this form $\phi$ does not seem to be valid, but I cannot see why.

Answer (score 2):

Your definition of $V^*$ is simply incorrect. $V^*$ only contains *linear* functionals, i.e. $f(x+\lambda y) = f(x) + \lambda f(y)$ for all $x, y \in V$, $\lambda \in \mathbb{K}$. Assuming this property for *any* $f:V \rightarrow \mathbb{K}$, observe:
$$
f(0) = f(0+0) = f(0)+f(0)
$$
Subtract $f(0)$ from both sides to get $0=f(0)$. So check whether your functional $\phi$ can be linear.

I wish you a fun math career.

Comment: Thank you, I knew it was a simple error, but have made it clearer to me.